# How can I execute an action if either input a or b is correct/true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, logical-operators

A user writes 'football' into my input bar and then the action on line 6 and 7 executes.
But I what if the user writes "Football", with a capital letter?
I tried to implement the "logial or" || but I couldn't get it to work.

```
var input = document.getElementById("user_input");
let footballTeams = ["Manchester","Barcelona","Copenhagen"]

if (input.value == "football") {
    alert("These cities have football teams:" +
          "\n" + footballTeams[0] + "," + " " + footballTeams[1] + "," + " " + footballTeams[2])
```

Comment: You can use `input.value.toLowerCase()` when comparing.

Comment: [String#toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: input.value.toLowerCase() === "football"

Comment: just normalize your input to a standard, like all lower case characters and check against it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (input.value.toLowerCase() == "football")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```js
if (input.value.toLowerCase() == "football") {
   console.log('inside if');
}
```

```html
<input id=input value="Football">
```

Comment: Please make at least some effort at explaining what's going on.

Comment: Worked right away! Thank you so much!